# C# reading from a XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read a XML in C#, using a button in WPF.
I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<date>
    <Disciplina nume="Disc1" cadru="Cadru1">
        <Student>
            <Nume>Student1</Nume>
            <Nota>9</Nota>
        </Student>
    </Disciplina> 
</date>
```

In the reading Button i have this code:

```
XmlTextReader rd = new XmlTextReader(@"Test.xml");
string dnume = "", dcadru = "", snume = "",snota="", element = "";

while ( rd.Read() )
{
    switch (rd.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            element = rd.Name;
            break;

        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            if (element == "Disciplina")
            {
                dnume = rd.GetAttribute("nume");
                dcadru = rd.GetAttribute("cadru");
            }
            else
                if (element == "Student")
                {

                }
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
            if (rd.Name == "Student1")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("");
            }
            break;
    }
}
rd.Close();
```

The problem is that I don't know how to read the information from the Student node. Can you help me?

Comment: Any reason you really need to use `XmlTextReader`? It's considerably simpler to just load an `XDocument`...

Comment: I need to use this because this is what I'm using at the University. Is something for an exam.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use `XmlReader` classes you can use a code like below in a Console Application:

```
var nestedLevel = 0;
var studentNestedLevel = 0;

using (var reader = XmlTextReader.Create(@"Test.xml"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                nestedLevel++;
                if (studentNestedLevel > 0)
                    Console.Write("{0}: ", reader.Name);
                if (reader.Name.ToLower() == "student")
                    studentNestedLevel = nestedLevel;
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                if (studentNestedLevel > 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.Value);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                if (studentNestedLevel > 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", reader.Name, reader.Value);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                nestedLevel--;
                if (reader.Name.ToLower() == "student")
                    studentNestedLevel = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```